# Prototype JS Hash Table alternative/solution for Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, hashtable

Hi everybody I'm a prototype js developer and I'm moving for work/client reasons to jquery.
 I'm a big fan of Prototype Hash `var h = new Hash();` class I know that in jQuery is not any hash table available at least in the core, I would like to know what it the best alternative to have a good practice/solution in a way to manage my data structure in a pretty same way as I do it with the hash table? of course using Jquery.

Comment: What kind of things are you storing in the hashtable?

Comment: normally I'm storing objects in the way { name : "myname", photos : ["1.jpg","2,jpg"], and : "so on"} basically what I do is ask for specify id in my hash table and retrieve the specific object of that id. for example if I  have a list of user in a webpage and an user with id = 3 is clicked. I asked for h.get(3) => { name : "", bla bla}.

Comment: You can use an object for that, too: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/NJpSB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only using strings as keys, you can use a plain old object (since you're no longer using Prototype, you don't have to worry much about overwriting things):

```
var h = {};
h.somekey = somevalue;
h.someotherkey = someothervalue;
h[dynamickey] = val;
```

Comment: I think I could do something like 
var h = {};
$.each(jsonResponeList,function(index, item){
  h.item.id = item; //I dont know if this is posible hahaha
}

Comment: @nahum: Certainly it's possible: `h.item = { id: item };`